# Importing Apache Mahout into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import Mahout into eclipse on a mac. I have installed Apache Mahout using:

```
$wget -c http://archive.apache.org/dist/mahout/0.9/mahout-distribution-0.9.tar.gz
$tar zxf mahout-distribution-0.9.tar.gz 
$cd mahout-distribution-0.9
$mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

When I run the last part I am getting the error:

```
Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory
```

What information do I need to put in this POM file?

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded `mahout-distribution-0.9.tar.gz` which will contain .jars that are intended to be pulled into an existing project. Since it contains the packaged .jars, there is no need for a pom.xml. This is different from the `*-src` downloads which contain the source code for the Mahout project, and a pom.xml for building the project from source.

I'm pretty sure you're not looking to build from source, so you will need an existing project and then pull in the Mahout .jars into that project. If you create a Maven project in Eclipse, you can use the pom.xml to pull in the necessary [Mahout dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout) without downloading them directly.